# Possible to use Hashcat to crack Ethereum password?

Tags: wallets, password, presale

I have a Ethereum presale wallet and the password i recorded for it doesn't work.
I now have a list of over 200 possible passwords for it.
Is it simply a matter of trying to use SHA3 in Hashcat with the bkp part of the wallet.json file or am I deluded and it is much more complicated than that?